# regular expression in email validation javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am doing email regular expression validation for the email and I am stuck on one point using 
following expression if user enter something like `abc.abc` then this expression works fine but when user enters `advxyz@pqr.com` then it doesn't work

```
var myreg = new RegExp(/([a-z0-9.]+)@([a-z0-9]+)\.([a-z0-9]+)/i);
var patter =  myreg.test(document.getElementById("email").value)
alert(patter)
if(patter == false){
  errorMsg.push("email Formate Error Ex:firstname.lastname@abc.com");
}
```

I want that user must enter his email in this formate like `firstname.lastname@abc.com/.ca/.org`

Comment: what do you mean *works* and *doesn't work*, your RE looks OK, except there is no need to use `new RegExp()` wrap a `RegExp` instance.

Comment: I'd suggest this very forgiving regex: `/[^@]+@[^@]/`, otherwise you can't know for sure if you're leaving some valid email out or you end up with a million character regex. The _only_ way to know if an email is really valid is to send an email and get a response back.

Comment: `myreg.test("firstname.lastname@abc.com");` returns `true`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I guess that's how it doesn't work...

Comment: @xiaoyi Yeah I don't get this question. All the other examples given return true too.

Comment: my email id checking criteria is like firstname.lastname@abc.com if someone enter like jsmith@abc.com then it is error. there should be a "." in between firstname and lastnname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var pattern = /^[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+@[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+$/i;

pattern.test('firstname.lastname@abc.com');
// returns true;

pattern.test('jsmith@abc.com');
// returns false;

pattern.test("abc.abc");
// returns false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regular Expressions is probably the best way.

Here's an example
 (live demo):

```
function validateEmail(email) { 
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\ ".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email);
}
```

But keep in mind that one should not rely only upon JavaScript validation. JavaScript can easily be disabled. This should be validated on the server side as well.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/1168379)

Answer (score 0):

This work Perfectly for me.

```
/^[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9_\-])+([\.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\@((([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.){1,2})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,40})$/;
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this is helpful in resolving the issue  \b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,4}\b
Its case sensitive.

Answer (score -1):

Pattern for to validate email address is:

/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

use this pattern in Regex. and you can validate any email..